# Formatting issue after building app

Tags: cordova, onsen-ui

I used custom styles (like center) in list heading. In browser and iOS the stylesheet is honoured but in android (nexus 4,5) the alignment becomes left align.
Any feedback which custom styles can be used and which cannot?
Here is the code snippets I am using:

```
.header {
      font-weight: 500;
      text-align: center;
    } <!-- HTML Content-->
<input class="center header text-input text-input--transparent" ng-model="activeTaskList.title">{{activeTaskList.title}}</input> <!-- This is a list header -->
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean `ons-list-header`? If yes, in the CSS, inside the `.list_header` class, the `text-align` attribute is, by default, `left`. Just change it or add `!important` to your class, to override the default behaviour.